# Scrape data with cheerio and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used cheerio module to scrape list of products from a website. But have problem, website using "Infinite Scrolling" to load data (data load more when scroll down). So, cheerio can't get all products.

Can someone suggest me a solutions for this problem ? Thanks you.

Comment: just grab the data right from the api that they use to fill the content; watch the network tab in devtools as you scroll, note newly-added urls. then just call the url to get json directly, instead of trying to scrape HTML.

Comment: For common page info you can use https://github.com/Mitica/html-explorer

Answer (score 2):

You can check out what sort of queries the page performs when you scroll. Then just hit those queries yourself and get the data.

Alternatively you can try to use something like [node-phantom-simple](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-phantom-simple), trigger scroll via Phantom and scrape.

I would go with the first option myself.